# How to get the name of the calling function inside the called routine?

Tags: r

Is there a "non-Internal" way to get the caller's name, as the function `stop` does?

The idea is that I have a small function that checks the inputs and halts execution if some condition is not met. This function is called by several others, that use the same validation code. If the input is invalid, the caller's environment is dumped (so I can see arguments passed to the function), and execution halts.

Simplified example:

```
check <- function(x)
{
    if(x<0)
    {
        print(as.list(parent.frame()))

        evalq(stop("invalid input."), parent.frame())
    }
}

test <- function(x, y)
{
    check(x)
}
```

I thought that evaluating the expression `quote(stop("blah"))` in the caller's environment would make it show the caller's name. However, the result is the following:

```
test(-1, 2)

# $x
# [1] -1
# 
# $y
# [1] 2
# 
# Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : invalid input.
```

And this doesn't change if I use `parent.frame(n)` with `n>1` in `evalq`.

So here is the question, actually two questions: 1. Is there a way to get the name of the function that created an environment (assuming it was created as such)? 2. Why the workaround above fails?

EDIT: I said the workaround above fails because I wanted the error message to appear as

```
Error in test(x, y) : invalid input.
```

as if the `stop` statement were a part of `test` body. So question 2 can be restated as: 2': Why didn't the evaluation of `stop("invalid input.")` capture the caller's name, considering it was evaluated in the environment of the caller?

Comment: It's a little odd to do this in a special way for one function. Why not use `traceback()` which will work whenever any error is generated?

Comment: @hadley, I learned about `traceback` and `sys.call`(`s`) in this post. SO works :-). The ideia is that there are many functions which call `check` to validade their inputs. If `check` detects errors, it dumps the parent environment, so I can see all the inputs passed to the function, and stops. The problem with this is that I can't identify the function that called `check` and caused the error. I could use `options(error=traceback)`, but that dumps the entire stack call, and that may cause some clutter. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: if you need a **full reference (function  name, line number, source file)**, [follow here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59537482/684229)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Thanks @GavinSimpson and @RicardoSporta, but I've figured it out. I'll post an answer in case somebody searches for this in SO.

The name of the function that generated the current call can be retrieved by

```
deparse(sys.calls()[[sys.nframe()-1]])
```

This returns a string that contains not only the name of the function, but the entire call object. The name alone can be retrieve by subsetting `sys.calls()[[sys.nframe()-1]]` before deparsing.

I wanted this because I wrote a function that checks the arguments and halts execution in case of an error. But I wanted this function to (i) dump the environment and (ii) show name of the function one level above in the execution stack. (i) is easy, but I was stuck in (ii).

As for the second question in my post, this is what happens: the expression `stop("invalid input")` is evaluated in the environment of the `test` function, but this is not the same thing as if the expression was part of `test`'s body, because the execution *stack* is different in this 2 scenarios. In the latter case, `stop` has only `test` above it, but in the first, it has `eval`, `check` and then `test` upwards. The execution stack, returned by `sys.calls()` is not the same thing as the enclosing environments. This is what may cause confusion.

Comment: Or just `deparse(sys.call())`

Comment: @hadley, nope, that gets the *current* call. I want the call one level above.

Comment: @hadley weird but `sys.call(-1)` works for `readRDS` but for `write_csv` it returns `standardise_path(path, input = FALSE)`. Why??

Answer (score 25):

See `?match.call`. For example:

```
foo <- function() {
  match.call()[[1]]
}

foo()

as.character(foo())
```

which produces

```
> foo()
foo
> 
> as.character(foo())
[1] "foo"
```

A simplified version of your code is

```
check <- function(x) {
  match.call()[[1]]
}

test <- function(y) {
  check(y)
}
```

giving

```
> test(2)
check
> as.character(test(2))
[1] "check"
```

Note `match.call()` works via the use of `sys.call()` (actually it calls `sys.call(sys.parent())`) when called as I did above with no arguments. So you may wish to consult `?sys.call` too.

Comment: Actually I wanted `check` to capture `test`'s name, not the other way round. But following your links, I figured it out: it can be done with `deparse(sys.calls()[[sys.nframe()-1]])`.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Ah, sorry, I missed that detail. Glad it helped anyway though. You could of course capture the call at the `test` level and pass it on, but `sys.call()` is neater.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I'd be interested to see how you would accomplish this with sys.call(). Sorry-I hadn't read far enough below.

Comment: @GavinSimpson This method fails when called within a namespace (e.g. as in `package::check(1)`). In my version of R, this will return a vector of characters `c("::", "package", "check")`. The preferred call is `deparse(match.call()[[1]])`.

Answer (score 11):

For the record, as Hadley has suggested, you can use `sys.call()`. For example:

```
funx = function(...) {
    callingFun = as.list(sys.call(-1))[[1]]
    calledFun = as.list(sys.call())[[1]]
    message(paste(callingFun, " is calling ", calledFun, sep=""))
}

funy = function(...) {funx(...)}

> funy(a = 1, b = 2)
funy is calling funx
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative way with the `rlang` package:

```r
f <- function() {
  name <- rlang::call_frame(n = 2)$fn_name
  rlang::abort(paste("The function", name, "was called and I throw an error."))
}
g <- function() f()
g()
#> Error: The function g was called and I throw an error.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: `rlang::call_frame` is now deprecated and replaced by `rlang::trace_back()` (note the underscore in the function name).

Answer (score 3):

Question #1 is answered by Gavin (use `match.call`).

However, based on what you are describing, you should also look at `traceback()`, the output of which you can pass to other functions.

---

#### As for **Question #2**:

It isn't failing, but working exactly as expected.   The error you are seeing is not an error in the true sense, but rather the error from your `stop(.)` function.

If you look at `print(evalq)`, you will see that it in turn calls `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos))` where `expr` is your `stop("invalid input.")`

#### The correct workaround is to use one more level of quoting

```
  evalq(quote(stop("invalid input.")))
  # stop("invalid input.")
```

Comment: Sorry, my second question wasn't very clear. See the edit above. I thought that `evalq(stop("invalid input."), parent.frame())` would give the same result as if the parent function had a `stop("invalid input.")` statement in its body.

Answer (score 0):

To get the function name of the function above, you can simply use:

```
gsub(pattern="^([A-Za-z0-9]+)(\\({1})(.*)(\\){1})$",replacement="\\1",x=deparse(sys.call(-1)))
```