# Code in R package: find out *which* package/namespace it is in

Tags: r, package

Is there a way code in an R package can find out *which* package or namespace it belongs to?

---

Background: I find I have common code between packages that just differs in the package name. One common *example* is `tests/testthat.R`:

```
library(testthat)
library(ShiftedExcitation)

test_check("ShiftedExcitation")
```

If the code could find out to which package or namespace it belongs, I could avoid a number of places where the package name is now given.

---

Right now I define a hidden variable that contains the package name, say

`.PKG <- "ShiftedExcitation"`

and then use *something along the lines of* *

```
library(testthat)
library(.PKG, character.only = TRUE)

test_check(.PKG)
```

but I'm curious whether a more elegant solution exists.

* I did not get this working so far as `testthat.R` is evaluated outside the package namespace. It does work for defining a `unittest` function inside the package code, though.

Comment: You might be able to use `.getNameSpace(match.call()[[1]])` which grabs the function's name as argument.    possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595478/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-function-inside-the-called-routine

Comment: `getNamespaceName(topenv())` ? E.g., `debug(lm); lm(); getNamespaceName(topenv())`

Comment: @MartinMorgan: `topenv` is almost the answer - just that the `testthat` namespace can be before the pacakge in the `search ()` path.

Answer (score 1):

Approaching an answer:

@MartinMorgan's hint to use `topenv ()` is quite close. But it turns out that while running unit tests with `testthat`, `testthat` is *before* the package namespace in the search path.

So this is the current state:

```
.findmyname <- function() {
    pkgs <- .packages ()

    if (pkgs [1] == "testthat")
        pkgs [2]
    else
        pkgs [1]
}
```

This function finds the name of the package in question both from within the package and in `tests/testthat.R`. (Of course, any `.findmyname ()` defined within the package is not known in `tests/testthat.R` before the `library` call...)

Comment: Looks like the first through third lines could probably be replaced with `pkgs <- .packages()`