# Get a call to a higher level function from inside a lower level function in R

Tags: r, function, call

Consider the following `R` code:

```
A = 1
B = 6
Fun2 <- function(v1, v2) Fun1(v1, v2)
Fun1 <- function(d, e)   print(match.call())
Fun2(A, B)
```

Now the result is:

```
Fun2(A, B)
## Fun1(d = v1, e = v2)
```

Is it possible from inside `Fun1` to get either a whole call to `Fun2` or just variable names, that were passed to `Fun2`. I imagine, that the result should look like `print(match.call())` was inside `Fun2`:

```
Fun2(A, B)
## Fun2(v1 = A, v2 = B)
```

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595478/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-function-inside-the-called-routine/15621405#15621405

Comment: If you just want the variable names, try `Fun1 <- function(d, e)   as.list(sys.call(1))[-1]`

Comment: I found out, that what I really needed was
`print(match.call(definition = sys.function(sys.parent(2)), call = sys.call(sys.parent(2))))`. 
Thank you for getting me on a right way :)