# Specify the calling function for an error message in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm working on an R package where the same input-checking functions are called by multiple "actual" functions that are exported to users. If I use a simple `stop()` call, the error message is going to say that an error occurred in the input-checking function, which is not that useful...

I thought I'd get around this by wrapping the call to the input-checking function inside a `tryCatch()`, and then handling the error in the outer function. This does mostly what I want, but doesn't quite give the output that I'd like. The closest I've come is the following:

```
f <- function(i) {
    tryCatch({
        check_input(i)
    }, error = function(e) stop("in f: ", e$message, call. = FALSE)
    )
}

check_input <- function(i) {
    if(i < 0)
        stop("i is negative, value given was ", i)
}

f(-1)
# Error: in f: i is negative, value given was -1
```

Ideally, I'd like the error message to be

`Error in f: i is negative, value given was -1`

, which would be the case if `stop` were called within `f()` instead of `check_input()`.

Comment: It would probably be easier to pass the name of the calling function to your `check_input` function and format the error message there. But there is no way to fool the build in `stop()` function to use the name a function other than the one where the stop actually occurred. You'd need to format the message yourself as you have done,

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595478/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-function-inside-the-called-routine

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I was just playing around with `sys.call()` myself, but missed the use of `deparse()`. I'll keep this open for a while longer, but it sounds like this is as close as it will get.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can grab the name of the function from the call stack and paste it in to the error message

```
f <- function(i) {
  check_input(i)
}
g <- function(i) {
  check_input(i)
}

check_input <- function(i, from=deparse(sys.calls()[[sys.nframe()-1]][[1]])) {
  getmsg <- function(m) ifelse(!is.null(from), paste0("in ", from, ": ", m), m)
  if(i < 0)
    stop(getmsg(paste0("i is negative, value given was ", i)), call. = FALSE)
}

f(-1)
#  Error: in f: i is negative, value given was -1
g(-1)
#  Error: in g: i is negative, value given was -1
```

You could also call `check_input(i, from="otherfunction")` to show whatever function name you want or `check_input(i, from=NULL)` to suppress the function name.